# Ubuntu LAMP Git clone Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh-keys, digital-ocean

I have set up a LAMP application on my droplet

I have used my set DO ssh key which is the same used for my mac and my bitbucket account.

I install git and create a folder at the /var/www level.

CD into the folder and run my git clone command but get the following error

Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.167' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your key hasn't been added to your key chain. Are you running git on your DO server or your mac? Either way run the following command:

```
ssh-add {path to ssh key}
```

and then try and clone again. Typically your ssh keys will be stored ~/.ssh but maybe somewhere else depending on your configuration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also looking at your error sounds like permissions when cloning into /var/www. Strictly speaking this is not best practice but trying running git clone with sudo.